# Store new permanent table in schema using compute

Tags: r, sql-server, dbi, dbplyr

I want to use  `dbplyr` syntax to do some `JOIN` / `FILTER` operations on some tables and store the results back to the Database **without** collecting it first.

From what I read `compute(..., temporary = FALSE, ...)` should be doing that, however I struggle of how to provide the fully qualified name (that is `database.schema.table_name`) to the table where I want to store

I know about `DBI::Id` and `dbplyr::in_schema` but I do not know how use them properly. A try with `sql` did at least what I wanted (created the table) but resulted in a (spurios?) error.

What do I need to do?

### Some NoReprex

```r
library(DBI)
library(dbplyr)

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "myserver")

## do __not__ collect the data
my_frame <- con %>%
   tbl(Id(catalog = "mydb", schema = "dbo", table = "mytable")) %>%
   inner_join(con %>% tbl(Id(catalog = "mydb", schema = "dbo", 
                             table = "yetanothertable")),
              "id")

compute(my_frame,
        # Id(catalog = "mydb", schema = "dbo", table = "mynewtable"), # (1)
        # in_schema("dbo", "mynewtable"),                             # (2),
        sql("mydb.dbo.mynewtable"),                                   # (3)
        FALSE)
```

I get different error depending on th variant I am using

```r
# (1)
## Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
##   error in evaluating the argument 'conn' in selecting a method for function 
## 'dbQuoteIdentifier': argument "con" is missing, with no default

# (2)
## Error in escape(x$schema, con = con) : 
##   argument "con" is missing, with no default

# (3)
## Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.  
##            [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. 
## <SQL> 'SELECT *
## FROM (my.fully_qualified.name) "q02"
## WHERE (0 = 1)'
```

P.S.: I really want to be able to save the table with the **fully** qualified name, that is including the database name (though it is the same in this simplified example). So a `dbConnect(..., database = <somedb>)` won't solve my problem in the long run.

P.P.S: I am looking for a `compute` solution. I know I could construct the `SQL` myself, but I am really interested to see whether I can use the `dbplyr` abstraction layer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have previously preferred the solution that involves writing some SQL (As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67577301/7742981) answer). But as you exclude this approach in your question, I tested and found a way to do it without writing SQL.

We are going to use `db_compute` instead of `compute`.

- The [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/compute.html) for `compute` states that "compute() stores results in a remote temporary table". So I took this to mean we can not write permanent tables using `compute`.
- The [documentation](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/db_copy_to.html) for `db_compute` says very little. But it appears alongside `db_copy_to` which has a purpose similar to what we are looking for. So it was worth trying (and it works).

**General setup**

```r
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)

# connect to database
connection_string = "..."
db_connection = dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = connection_string)

# remote table
remote_table = tbl(db_connection, from = in_schema("schema","table"))
top_rows = remote_table %>%
  head()
```

**Testing compute**

```r
top_rows %>% show_query()
# <SQL>
# SELECT TOP (6) *
# FROM [database_name].[schema_name].[table_name]

top_rows = top_rows %>%
  compute()
# Created a temporary table named: #dbplyr_002

top_rows %>% show_query()
# <SQL>
# SELECT *
# FROM #dbplyr_.002
```

So we can see `compute` writes a temporary table. Hence if we did some complex processing (instead of just taking the top few rows) `compute` would be an effective way to storing the processed table so we can  avoid repeating the complex processing every time we query it.

But because it is temporary, the table should disappear when we disconnect from the database: `DBI::dbDisconnect(db_connection)`.

**Testing db_compute**

```r
out = db_compute(
  con = db_connection,
  table = in_schema("schema","new_table"),
  sql = sql_render(top_rows),
  temporary = FALSE
)

out
# <IDENT> database_name.schema_name.new_table

# reconnect
new_remote_table = tbl(db_connection, from = in_schema("schema","new_table"))
```

So we can now access the new (permanent) table from within R. I also checked and confirmed that the table exists in the database with an SQL query.

**Note** that as `db_compute` has minimal documentation, it is not clear whether it is intended to be used in this way. I have tested the above and it worked. But without additional documentation, use at your own risk.

Comment: For specifying the database name, I have done this using `in_schema` something like this: `tbl(db_con, from = in_schema("db_name.schema_name","table_name")`. For one of the later dbplyr updates, I think you need to use the `sql` command as well: `tbl(db_con, from = in_schema(sql("db_name.schema_name"),"table_name")`. But these details probably need another question to address.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot. FYI (And I will add that as an answer as well): the major trick was `in_schema(sql("db_name.schema_name"), "table_name")` as pointed out by you. So no need to fall back to `db_compute`. Great +1!

Comment: And yes the documentation for `compute` is misleading as it only speaks about temporary tables. However, if you follow the link in the very doc to [`compute.tbl_sql`](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/collapse.tbl_sql.html) you will see the `temporary` flag, which cna be used to store the results permanently.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, thanks to Simon's answer I finally got the correct way of providing the fully qualified table name (i.e. containing database, schema and table name). With this piece of information, one can rely on  `compute` and everything works like a charm. You just have to provide the database name as part of the schema and make sure to escape if via `sql`:

```
compute(my_frame,
        # in_schema("mydb.dbo", "mynewtable") would __not__ work
        in_schema(sql("mydb.dbo"), "mynewtable"), 
        FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just a few hours trying to figure why I couldnt get Simon's code to work.

Turns out that a connection created with pool::dbPool() fails  to compute, but a connection created with DBI::dbConnect() works.    I submitted an issue here https://github.com/rstudio/pool/issues/179

Sample code that works/fails with pool vs dbi

```
# libraries -----
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)
library(pool)
library(dplyr)
library(odbc)
# connect using pool and con ----
pool <- pool::dbPool(drv = odbc::odbc(),
                     driver = "{ODBC17}",
                     uid = Sys.getenv("AZURE_UID"),          
                     pwd = Sys.getenv("AZURE_PWD"),        
                     server = Sys.getenv("AZURE_SERVER"),     
                     database = Sys.getenv("AZURE_DATABASE"),  
                     Authentication = "ActiveDirectoryPassword",
                     port = 1433,
                     minSize = 0, ## default is 1 which often leaves connections hanging (not cool)
                     idleTimeout = 600, ## 10 minutes until idle connection is closed, takes ~1 second to reopen
                     encoding = "UTF-8",
                     encrypt = "yes")

con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  Driver   = "{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}",
  Server   = Sys.getenv("AZURE_SERVER"),
  Database = Sys.getenv("AZURE_DATABASE"),
  UID      = Sys.getenv('AZURE_UID'),
  PWD      = Sys.getenv('AZURE_PWD'),
  Port     = 1433,
  Authentication = "ActiveDirectoryPassword",
  Encrypt  = "yes"
)



# upload iris to synapse  ----
#DBI::dbWriteTable(con, DBI::Id(schema = "my_schema",   table = "iris"),  value = iris, overwrite = TRUE) # slow but works

#  POOL --this doesnt work  -----

pool_iris <- tbl(pool,   dbplyr::in_schema(sql("my_schema"),"iris"))


pool_query <- pool_iris %>%
  head(10)

compute(pool_query, dbplyr::in_schema(sql("my_schema"),"iris_computed_from_pool"), temporary = FALSE)
# Error in UseMethod("sql_escape_ident") :
#   no applicable method for 'sql_escape_ident' applied to an object of class "c('Pool', 'R6')"


#  DBCONNECT - this works (same code) -----

con_iris <- tbl(con,   dbplyr::in_schema(sql("my_schema"),"iris"))


con_query <- con_iris %>%
  head(10)

compute(con_query, dbplyr::in_schema(sql("my_schema"),"iris_computed_from_con"), temporary = FALSE)


#  Source:   table<my_schema."iris_computed_from_con"> [10 x 5]
# # Database: Microsoft SQL Server 12.00.2531[usersqldatabaseXXXX@domainsqldatabaseXXXX.com@sqlserversqldatabaseXXXX/sqldatabaseXXXX]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>
#  1          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa
#  2          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2 setosa
#  3          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1 setosa
#  4          6.4         3.1          5.5         1.8 virginica
#  5          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa



sessioninfo::session_info()
# ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#  setting  value
#  version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#  os       OpenShift Enterprise
#  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#  ui       RStudio
#  language (EN)
#  collate  en_CA.UTF-8
#  ctype    en_CA.UTF-8
#  tz       America/Toronto
#  date     2024-02-06
#  rstudio  2023.06.0+421.pro1 Mountain Hydrangea (server)
#  pandoc   3.1.1 @ /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#
# ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#  ! package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#  P bit           4.0.5   2022-11-15 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P bit64         4.0.5   2020-08-30 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P blob          1.2.4   2023-03-17 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P cli           3.6.0   2023-01-09 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P DBI         * 1.1.3   2022-06-18 [?] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#  P dbplyr      * 2.3.2   2023-03-21 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P digest        0.6.31  2022-12-11 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P dplyr       * 1.1.0   2023-01-29 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P evaluate      0.20    2023-01-17 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P fansi         1.0.4   2023-01-22 [?] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#  P fastmap       1.1.1   2023-02-24 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P generics      0.1.3   2022-07-05 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P hms           1.1.3   2023-03-21 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P htmltools     0.5.7   2023-11-03 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P knitr         1.42    2023-01-25 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P later         1.3.0   2021-08-18 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P lifecycle     1.0.3   2022-10-07 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#    magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P odbc        * 1.4.2   2024-01-22 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P pillar        1.8.1   2022-08-19 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.3)
#  P pool        * 1.0.1   2023-02-21 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P purrr         1.0.1   2023-01-10 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#    R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P Rcpp          1.0.10  2023-01-22 [?] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#    renv          1.0.3   2023-09-19 [1] RSPM (R 4.0.2)
#  P rlang         1.1.0   2023-03-14 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P rmarkdown     2.20    2023-01-19 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P rstudioapi    0.15.0  2023-07-07 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P tibble        3.2.1   2023-03-20 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P tidyselect    1.2.0   2022-10-10 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P utf8          1.2.3   2023-01-31 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P vctrs         0.6.0   2023-03-16 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P xfun          0.37    2023-01-31 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#  P yaml          2.3.7   2023-01-23 [?] RSPM (R 4.0.5)
#
#  [1] /XXXX/renv/library/R-4.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#  [2] /opt/R/4.0.2/lib/R/library
#
#  P ── Loaded and on-disk path mismatch.
```